# Autodesk-Forge bucket system: New versioning

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, bucket, autodesk-model-derivative

I am wondering of what is the best practise for handling new version of the same model in the Data Management API [Bucket](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/.) system

Currently, I have one bucket per user and the files with same name overwrites the existing model when doing a svf/svf2 conversion.

In order to handle model versioning in be the best manner, should I :

1. create one bucket per file converted

or

2. continue with one bucket per user.

If 1): is there a limitation of number of buckets which is possible to create?

else 2): How do I get the translation to accept an bucketKey different than the file name? (As it is now, the uploaded file need to be the filename to get the translation going.)

In advance, cheers for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to translate a file, you **do not** have to keep the original **file name**, but you do need to keep the **file extension** (e.g. *.rvt), so that the **Model Derivative** service knows which translator to use. So you could just create files with different names: perhaps add a suffix like "**_v1**" etc or generate random names and keep track of which file is what **version** of what **model** in a database. Up to you.

There is no limit on number of buckets, but it might be an overkill to have a separate one for each file.